# an error in php and xml

Tags: php, xml

I know i have bothered all of you with my questions but i have a question about php and xml

i am trying to store all the values of the pages in xml so i would create a multilingual website

after searching i have got to a way but and i tried to alter it a little bit
there is my xml files:

en.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>

    <!--Page Titles-->
    <freeEaHdr>
        <![CDATA[Get in the game!]]>
    </freeEaHdr>
    <freeEaSubhdr>
        <![CDATA[Load up your Xperia™ PLAY with 4 exciting EA titles for<span style="color:#ff9c00;"> FREE</span>]]>
    </freeEaSubhdr>
    <!--Page Titles-->

</main>
```

and there is my ar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>

    <!--Page Titles-->
    <freeEaHdr>
        <![CDATA[ادخل اللعبة]]>
    </freeEaHdr>
    <freeEaSubhdr>
        <![CDATA[حمل الاكسبيريا الان]]>
    </freeEaSubhdr>
    <!--Page Titles-->

</main>
```

and i have created an select_lang.php

```
<?php
function select_lang(){
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
        if($lang == "en"){
            $xml = simplexml_load_file("en.xml");
        } else{
            $xml = simplexml_load_file("ar.xml");
        } 
    } else {
            $xml = simplexml_load_file("en.xml");
    }
    return $xml;
}
?>
```

and the final page was index.php

```
<?php
include("select_lang.php");
select_lang();
?>
<div><?php echo $xml->freeEaHdr; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $xml-> freeEaSubhdr; ?></div>
<a href="?lang=en">english</a>
<a href="?lang=ar">arabic</a>
```

now of course i get errors in index.php as for the main xml variable is not defined so if anybody has a solution

Thanks in advance

and sorry for bothering you

Comment: Can you post the actual error? Also, you have a space between `-> and freeEaSubhdr`: <?php echo $xml-> freeEaSubhdr; ?>

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: xml in /Users/moustafa/Sites/lang_test/index.php on line 5

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/moustafa/Sites/lang_test/index.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: xml in /Users/moustafa/Sites/lang_test/index.php on line 6

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/moustafa/Sites/lang_test/index.php on line 6
english arabic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select_lang()` function returns the created SimpleXML object `$xml`. You then try to use this object in your index.php file, but you haven't actually assigned the return value of `select_lang()` to anything.

Simply doing

```
$xml = select_lang();
```

instead of

```
select_lang();
```

will let you actually use the returned XML object in your index.php file.

Comment: Thanks alot really you have saved the day thanks you very very very much

Answer (score 0):

try to:

```
<?php
include("select_lang.php");
$xml = select_lang(); //change this line
?>
```